# Select groups of row only having specific value?

Tags: mysql

I want to select rows of products group by product_group_id that **only** have is_shown = 1.

```
Product Table
+----+------------------+---------+----------+
| id | product_group_id |   name  | is_shown |
+----+------------------+---------+----------+
| 1  |        1         |  apple  |     1    |
| 2  |        1         |  orange |     1    |
| 3  |        1         |  kiwi   |     0    |
| 4  |        2         |  table  |     1    |
+----+------------------+---------+----------+
```

My sql statement is

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE is_shown = 1 GROUP BY product_group_id
```

What I need is a rows that **only** have is_shown = 1.

So My expected result is I will only get a row

```
Product Table
+----+------------------+---------+----------+
| id | product_group_id |   name  | is_shown |
+----+------------------+---------+----------+
| 4  |        2         |  table  |     1    |
+----+------------------+---------+----------+
```

Buy I still get a product_group_id = 1.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: what is the reason for your expected result...???

Comment: Do you mean only `shown = 1` and `product_group_id != 1` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery for this.
Get all the product_group_id and use it to filter rows.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  Products 
WHERE 
  product_group_id IN 
  (
    SELECT 
      product_group_id 
    FROM 
      Products 
    GROUP BY
      product_group_id 
    HAVING 
      min(is_shown) = 1
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Then just exclude them:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Product
WHERE 
    product_group_id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            product_group_id
        FROM
            Product
        WHERE
            is_shown = 0
    )
```

Select all products **except** that `product_group_id`, that have `is_shown =0`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it Helpful...

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  Product 
WHERE
  product_group_id NOT IN ( 
    SELECT
      product_group_id 
    FROM
      Product 
    WHERE
      is_shown != 1
  ) 
GROUP BY
  product_group_id
```

Comment: You can't just `GROUP BY` without using appropriate aggregate functions in your `SELECT`.